# why i need to do a string interpolation to my string value in my dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am a beginner, I send a request to login to a server, the server need username, password, ket and registration ID (token for Firebase cloud Messaging), as we can see below the regID is actually  a string

[image]

but why do i need to do a string interpolation of `regID`?

i think in the `parameters` dictionary, it will be alright if i write just `regID` as the value of "registrationId"

```
"registrationId" : regID
```

like that,

**but it doesn't work, the server will not receive that registrationID**, so I have to write like this

```
"registrationId" : "\(regID)"
```

the regID is actually a string, but i don't understand why I have to do string interpolation to a string value. the code i use are below

```
     @IBAction func loginButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {

                self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()


                guard let regID = registrationID else {return}

                // send request to server
                let url = URLService.login.endPoint

                let parameters = [
                    "loginUser" : usernameTextField.text!,
                    "password" : passwordTextField.text!,
                    "registrationId" : "\(regID)",
                    "key" : "@PakuAttendance20171207@"

                ]

// the networking service below is actually alamofire
                NetworkingService.fetchJSON(url: url, methodUsed: .post, parameters: parameters) { (result) in

                    switch result {
                    case .failure(let error) :
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.showAlert(alertTitle: "Sorry", alertMessage: error.localizedDescription, actionTitle: "Back")
                    case .success(let jsonFromServer) :

        }
```

the registrationID value is :

> dYhReMYcbZs:APA91bGK9fH_Xa5lctmuH3e4m1zY9gUsVMfR34zsBHoVYStLITIcWZKr30Mu-0NqLuSE-rr25V2BnwAdpWvdAzW7i1BNFokz33pEoSr2fBZd468z0SwOGTytnrFHdNKFhTlGFHNZF3

Comment: What made you think that ___you have to use String interpolation___?

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Comment: "the regID is actually a string." Why do you believe this? Have you checked the type of `regID`? (Don't just print it out; check the value. Alt-click the variable, or `print(type(of: regID))`. "the server will not receive that registrationID" What do you mean by "will not receive." In what way does it not receive the value? Do you receive an error? Is it empty? Some other value?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need string interpolation there. You are right that:

```
"registrationId" : regID
```

is enough.